# Expecting new line or a semicolon

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to display new page and start navigating automatically whenever user inputs both location in the input field. For that i am using useEffect method. But the object created is not working as expected and giving me error as

`, or ) expected`

```
ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected &quot;,&quot;


Expecting newline or semicolon
```

Can someone help me. As i am learning, i am new to all these. I have encountered almost same problem before. But i managed to fix it. It may be problem with the object. Anyone who can solve this, please explain it in detail.
Code is as follow:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {GooglePlacesAutocomplete} from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

import styles from './styles';

const DestinationSearch = props => {
  const [originPlace, setOriginPlace] = useState({initalState: 'null'});
  const [destinationPlace, setDestinationPlace] = useState({
    initalState: 'null',
  });
  useEffect(effect:()=>{
    if(originPlace && destinationPlace) {}
  },deps[originPlace, destinationPlace])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="From where?"
          onPress={(
            data: GooglePlaceData,
            details: GooglePlaceDetail | null = null,
          ) => {
            setDestinationPlace({value: {data, details}});
            console.log(data, details);
          }}
          styles={{
            textInput: styles.textInput,
          }}
          fetchDetails
          query={{
            key: 'AIzaSyB3rsn2ecpXZ8p9d8J_kLIH59rxt9KV6Rs',
            language: 'en',
          }}
        />

        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="Where to?"
          onPress={(
            data: GooglePlaceData,
            details: GooglePlaceDetail | null = null,
          ) => {
            setDestinationPlace({value: {data, details}});
            console.log(data, details);
          }}
          styles={{
            textInput: styles.textInput,
          }}
          fetchDetails
          query={{
            key: 'AIzaSyB3rsn2ecpXZ8p9d8J_kLIH59rxt9KV6Rs',
            language: 'en',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default DestinationSearch;
```

Comment: `useEffect(effect:()=>{ ... },deps[originPlace, destinationPlace])` JS doesn't support named function arguments like that. And your `useState` calls are valid, but also incorrect - I'm quite sure that `originPlace` is not supposed to be an object with a property `initialState`. And 3rd: `'null'` is a string; you probably mean `null`

Comment: how to fix this? would appreciate any help

Comment: Does the error say what row and column the error occurred at?

Comment: yes sir it is 12, 13 and 14

Comment: "useEffect(effect:()=>{..." should be "useEffect(()=>{..." and after that that ",deps" is all messed up... What is that comma? Plus your parentheses are wrong.

Comment: What should i do instead of that?